# Border strokes changes on SVGs

Tags: svg

[image]

Hi,
I want to generate an SVG that looks like the attached image. the area I am having trouble with the most is the different stroke colors - darker on top and lighter on the bottom.
any ideas on how to implement it?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want a linearGradient. There's an [example here](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/tryit.asp?filename=trysvg_linear2), you'll have to choose appropriate colours for your use case but you can experiment using the interface there.

Comment: I am not talking about the gradient in the button itself, but about the gradient in the button's border.

Comment: A gradient is a gradient is a gradient. Use a rect and put a gradient on its stroke.